# After enable multisite enviroment in wordpress site creation wizard not working

Tags: plugins, multisite

After enable multisite environment in wordpress site creation wizard not working.

If I am installing [Site Creation Wizard (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/site-creation-wizard/) **without enable multisite** there seems option "Create new site" in dashboard.

But If I install that plugin after I enabled multisite, the "Create New Site" option does not seems to be on the dashboard any longer. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, With 3.1, Network has it's own control panel. Navigate to the top right of your Dashboard and you will see the link to "network." You should then be able to create a new site in that panel view.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Network Admin area instead.